# Check if jQuery clicked element an anchor containing an img

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if the clicked element was an anchor containing an img?

So for example I want to check if this element was clicked:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="#" />
<a/>
```

```js
jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
    // e.target.hereIsWhereINeedHelp;
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wish to capture the "click" from any element:

```
jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
    if (jQuery(e.target).is('a') && jQuery(e.target).has('img')) {
        // code goes here
    }    
});
```

Whether you choose to prevent the "default behavior" is another question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.is("a")` and `.has("img")`:

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="#" />
<a/>

<script>
    jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
        var target = $( e.target );
        if ( target.is( "a" ) && target.has("img") ) {
            //Do what you want to do
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `has()` method to check if an element contains another:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this will stop the link from going anywhere.
    if ($(this).has('img')) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

You could also use `if ($(this).find('img').length)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `has()` method

```
this.has("img");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `has()` or `find()`

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the link redirection

    if ( $(this).has("img") ) {
        console.log("has image");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the clicked element is an anchor tag using `is`, and then use `find` to look for an `image`. If both are true then you `//do something`.

```
jQuery(document).click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if(el.is("a") && el.find("img").length > 0){
        //do something
    }
});
```